# why doesn't the css positioning work?

Tags: css

```
<div style="background-color:#303030;height:5.5%;">
<input type="text" style="border:1px solid;
                          top:50px;
                          bottom:10px;
                          height:90%;
                          left:20px;
                          width:25%;
                          " />
```

Here I have a dark div bar, with an input inside it. Why doesnt the top, bottom, left work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for positioning to work, you need to declare what type of positioning to use... `position: absolute;` `position:relative;` `position: fixed;` etc...

Comment: which one should I use to position it inside the div?

Comment: There's no definitive answer to that question. It depends greatly on what you wish to accomplish. For just a general default, go with `position: relative;`. Relative positioning will position the element in relation to its parent container. For more info on positioning see here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
```

Please note:

- Your div has a height of 5.5%, and inside you place an input field 50px from the top, with a height of 90%(!). That is a huge input field. It makes no sense. Use either relative or exact measurements.
- The div is missing a `</div>`
- Don't mix-up mark-up and style (css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the position of the element declared before you can position it in your page. The position property has 4 or 5 different settings. Inherit, absolute, fixed, static, and relative. Absolute won't work, because it needs a parent element that is positioned. Static is the default, and inherit inherits. Fixed freezes the element to the browser window. When you scroll, it won't move. Relative positions it from where it's supposed to be, so I think that's the one you would want.